# Application crashes when firebase contains a List

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that saves in firebase current location (city name etc), id, and a list with points so i can save a polyline. Import in firebase is succesfull. The problem is when i go to another activity that contains a listview with all the city names of the firebase the app crashes. I tried to make it without the list in firebase and works fine. So the problem exists only when firebase contains the list with the points.

This is an example of my firebase. Here, "ola' is the list that contains the points and i have it only in the last one. If i remove the last one, the app works fine.

[image]

```
import java.util.List;




public class Paths {
String id;
String name;
String city;
String nomos;
String perifereia;
List<Ola> ola;



public Paths(){

}



public Paths(String id, String name, String city, String nomos, String perifereia, List<Ola> ola) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
    this.nomos = nomos;
    this.perifereia = perifereia;
    this.ola = ola;

}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public String getNomos() {
    return nomos;
}

public String getPerifereia() {
    return perifereia;
}

public List<Ola> getOla() {
    return ola;
}
```

.

```
public class Ola {

public double latitude;
public double longitude;


public Ola() {}


public Ola(double latitude, double longitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
```

}

And here is the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.spiros.mypath, PID: 28814
              com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.example.spiros.mypath.Ola
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                  at com.example.spiros.mypath.CitiesList$1.onDataChange(CitiesList.java:44)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

And that is the code that receives the data from firebase:

```
    databasePaths = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Paths");

    databasePaths.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot items: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                info = items.getValue(Paths.class);
                ArrayListCities.add(info.city);

            }


            adapterCities = new ArrayAdapter<>(CitiesList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayListCities);
            ListViewCities.setAdapter(adapterCities);
            adapterCities.notifyDataSetChanged();


            ListViewCities.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String selectedFromListCities = (ListViewCities.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());



                    Intent IntentGoN = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullListByCity.class);
                    IntentGoN.putExtra("city", selectedFromListCities);
                    startActivity(IntentGoN);

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please paste the related code (I suspect: `CitiesList.java`) too.

Comment: Ok i pasted it.

Comment: please confirm if you resolved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem

```
Class java.util.List has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead
```

List needs to be told what kind of objects it's holding. So you will need to create a model class that can take in the variable `ola`

First Ensure your firebase database structure is

```
key-|
---city
---....
---ola|
-------0|
---------latitude
---------longitude
-------1|
---------...
```

Then create a model class for ola with the two objects(latitude and longitude) with constructors

And now you can use list as

```
List<Ola> ola;
```

Comment: I made it but it crashes again with the error: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.example.name.mypath.Ola

Comment: it means you are casting a list to the object Ola. You should cast a list to a list. `List<Ola>` is a list but 'Ola' is the data object

Comment: @MrUmbra you skipped the first step. Confirm your data structure. it should be fom ola to the list (0,1,2). currently it is from ola then to 0 then to list(0,1,2)

Comment: Can you tell me how can i change it?

Comment: export one entry, post it on github, comment here the link, ill change it for you then you can import it

Comment: I found a solution, Lucem. I just used the line String infos = items.child("name").getValue(String.class); Thank for your help.

Comment: i see that i must change the database structure to the way you said. If you can change it for me, man. I uploaded to google drive because i don't use github and i can't understand it. If you fix it, post the link.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PL7B4q4EdUK2UT7VxlqUnscX03ZmfiIf

Comment: Actually i made it. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: sorry i hadnt seen. am glad

Comment: Its ok i made it myself. Like you said, the mistake was in database structure. Thank you.